# PostgresSQL database has date field, I want all data but the date column as year only

Tags: postgresql, datetime, subquery

I have data that has a date column in the full format but would like the output to only represent the year.

eg: from

```
SELECT * FROM tablename;
```

I want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WITH 'newdatefield' as SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP 'datefield');
```

I'm not great at SQL - I remember that something like this can be done but can't find how to do it again.

Comment: WITH doesn't belong at this position. Where did you find this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this one:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR from datefield), The, Other, Fields, You, Want FROM tableName
```